# convert rgba color codes 255,255,255,255 to kivy color codes in 1,1,1,1

Tags: python, colors, kivy

In order to specify any color value in kivy we need to specify values from 0 to 1 i.e. 
color defaults to [1,1,1,1] and can contain values between 0 and 1 , however rgba codes which are readily available for other languages are always specified from 0 to 255 and i usually refer them from any web link as in 
http://www.rapidtables.com/web/color/RGB_Color.htm

This helps even in various python toolkits example pyQt library however in kivy its different .

Does anyone know why its specified from 0 to 1 and if there s any way to code values used by various other languages to kivy color codes . for example what if i want to change rgb(192,192,192) to kivy color code ?

Comment: You can use this page [https://www.colorhexa.com/00274d](https://www.colorhexa.com/00274d) For using it you just need the hex code of the color you want and then you can use the RGB values that appear at the beginning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I think you can just divide it by 255:

```
float_color = color / 255.0
```

Comment: looks like its doing the job :)

Answer (score 15):

Though this doesnt really answer the question, but another simple way is using kivy's hex feature , an example in kv lang:

```
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: hex('#03A9F4')
```

Comment: I just want to point out that the COMMENT in this example isn't a comment but actually defines the `hex` function

Answer (score 8):

To avoid some divisions and speed up:

http://www.corecoding.com/utilities/rgb-or-hex-to-float.php

Comment: would be great if they added hex to rgba too.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [kivy.utils](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.utils.html) for more cool features, found this easy thing, before this I used to go to a [site](https://corecoding.com/utilities/rgb-or-hex-to-float.php) for converting hex to decimal rgb( coz I am too lazy to divide each rgb value by 255.

`#:import utils kivy.utils
<MainWindow>:
    Button:
      background_color: utils.get_color_from_hex('#58AE6F')`

The only issue with this approach is that you can't enter transparency, if you wish to use transparency you can very well use the [site](https://corecoding.com/utilities/rgb-or-hex-to-float.php) I mentioned to get decimals for 'rgb' and using percentage of transparency as 'a' value in 'rgba'.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following.

```
(**255**/255.0, **160**/255.0, **0**/255.0, 1)
```

So what you need to do is divide your RGB value with 255.0, so the above color will give you orange. All the numbers that have ** will be your RBG Colors.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see [here](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Color), in Kivy the first three numbers are just re-scaled RGB values to 0 and 1, and the last one is `alpha`. But remember you can set the mode, you could use `hsv` instead, not I guess you don't need that.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to register here a less conventional method, which I think is more organized and clean: Define a color converting function that you can import and use in your `.kv` file.

Define your function in a `func.py` module

```py
# color convert
def cc(color):
    return color / 255
```

Import it and use it in the `.kv` file

```
#:import cc func.cc
   
<YourBuildClass>:
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: 0, cc(102), cc(173)
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 0):

convert from regular rgba to kivy rgba

```py
def krgb(r,g,b,a):
    return (r/255,g/255,b/255,int(a==255),)
```